# C64 + DigiConnect SP messages sending as 1 char connections instead of full strings using BASIC

Tags: serial-port, commodore, retro-computing

Using a Commodore 64 with a GLINK LT RS-232 adapter connected to a Digi-Connect SP configured to send RAW TCP to a static IP/port on my home network.  Destination is a socat process passing traffic elsewhere with verbose logging.

Testing hitting socat from a bash shell on an OS X machine, issuing `curl http://192.168.1.91:1234` I get a valid response and the socat log shows

```
> 2018/12/29 22:06:50.168550  length=81 from=0 to=80
GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Host: 192.168.1.91:1234\r
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0\r
Accept: */*\r
\r
< 2018/12/29 22:06:50.169509  length=144 from=0 to=143

(followed by http response)
```

But when I run the following on the C64 BASIC code SNIPPET:

```
100 OPEN 2,2,3,CHR$(6)+CHR$(0)
110 GET#2,A$: REM TOSS NULL TO OPEN RCVR CHANNEL
120 PRINT#2,"GET /"
...
```

the socat log shows:

```
> 2018/12/29 22:11:38.952005  length=1 from=167 to=167
G> 2018/12/29 22:11:38.983674  length=1 from=168 to=168
E> 2018/12/29 22:11:39.015464  length=1 from=169 to=169
T> 2018/12/29 22:11:39.051758  length=1 from=170 to=170
 > 2018/12/29 22:11:39.084476  length=1 from=171 to=171
/> 2018/12/29 22:11:39.117131  length=1 from=172 to=172
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong on the C64 side to cause the individual char's to be sent or if it's an incorrect Digi-Connect setting.

Digi serial settings are:

- TCP Client Settings:

  - Automatically establish TCP connections

    - Always connect and maintain connection
  - Establish connection to the following network service:

    - Server: 192.168.1.91
    - Service: Raw TCP
    - TCP Port: 1234
    - Enable TCP Keep-Alive: On
- Basic Serial Settings

  - Baud: 300
  - Data bits: 8
  - Parity: None
  - Stop Bits: 0
  - Flow Control: Hardware
- Advanced Serial Settings

  - (nothing configured here)

Answer (score 1):

The individual characters was a red herring, the fix is simply to add a LF (ASCII 10) to the end of the message so the downstream web service understands that the message is finished.

Working example:

```
100 OPEN 2,2,3,CHR$(6)+CHR$(0)
110 PRINT#2,"GET /"
120 PRINT#2,CHR$(10)
```

(also of note - anything requiring correct upper/lower case will need PETSCII <-> ASCII conversions)